# How to edit the attributes of the <a> tag in topmenu $_menu

Tags: layout, category, menu

In `topmenu.phtml`, it calls the links from the `$_menu` block. I found you can edit this in `Navigation.php`, but I don't know how to add extra attributes to the `<a>` tag.

What I need is to set the target for all the links in `$_menu` to `"target='_top'"`.

Any idea of how I can do this?

Comment: vales,are you talk about magento topmenu???And which magento version ,are you using??

Comment: Sorry for late comment, but I am using Magento 1.7. And yes, I was talking about the topmenu.

But the answer Amit gave worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have taking about magento .`top menu is inherit from magento class Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu`.From function `_getHtml()` it creating html of menu..
Here you see  `<a>tag` just change here